# Automator check file type

Tags: applescript, finder, automator

I've got an `Ask for Finder Items` Automator action. How do I make it check whether the file is an image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "Filter Finder Items" and set a "Kind is image" rule.

I don't believe there is a way to perform a different action depending on the file type.